# Subsetting a data frame's column by it's respective levels and applying a function to each subset

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, lapply, quantile

I have some code that works when my values only have one factor level in the column "short_desc". It takes the "Value" and outputs the corresponding decile range in the column "Value.fc".

The data.frame before the manipulation looks like this:

[image: dataframe before manipulation]

I apply these lines of code to the dataframe "df":

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(Value.fc = cut2(Value, g=10),
     Value.fc = factor(sapply(str_extract_all(Value.fc, "\\d+"),
                              function(x) paste(x, collapse="-"))),
     Value.fc = reorder(Value.fc, Value))
```

And the result is column "Value.fc" which are decile factor ranges:

[image: manipulated dataframe]

The problem arises when the column "short_desc" has many levels.

I am unable to subset the observations by "short_desc" and apply the code to get each subset's decile "Value.fc". The resulting decile factor ranges are incorrect. I used the following code:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(short_desc) %>%
mutate(Value.fc = cut2(Value, g=10),
     Value.fc = factor(sapply(str_extract_all(Value.fc, "\\d+"),
                              function(x) paste(x, collapse="-"))),
     Value.fc = reorder(Value.fc, Value)) %>%
ungroup()
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

[image: grou_by() dataframe]

Any guidance would be appreciated. Sample data:

```
dput(head(df)) structure(list(state = c("Iowa", "Iowa", "Illinois"), short_desc = c("Corn, grain - yield, measured in bu / acre", "Corn, silage - yield, measured in tons / acre", "Corn, grain - yield, measured in bu / acre"), Value = c(137.8, 13.5, 153.3), FIPS = c("19001", "19001", "17001"), Value.fc = c("135-0-150", "13-0-14-5", "150-4-157"))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example data instead of images

Comment: dput(head(df))
structure(list(state = c("Iowa", "Iowa", "Illinois"), short_desc = c("Corn, grain - yield, measured in bu / acre", 
"Corn, silage - yield, measured in tons / acre", "Corn, grain - yield, measured in bu / acre"), Value = c(137.8, 
13.5, 153.3), FIPS = c("19001", "19001", "17001"), Value.fc = c("135-0-150", "13-0-14-5", "150-4-157"))